# How to read xml file and insert it into Database in Mule

Tags: xml, database, xpath, mule, mule-studio

I have an xml file :-

```
< getData >
< Data >
< id >321< /id >
< name >aa< /name >
< age >23< /age >
< designation >gfgf< /designation >
< /Data >
< /getData >
```

Where **ID** and **AGE** are integers .....  Now I want to insert these attributes of xml in Database using Mule... My Mule flow is :-

```
 < context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conf/DBConnectionProp.properties"/>
    < spring:beans>
        < spring:bean id="DB_Source" name="DB_Source" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource">
            < spring:property name="url" value="${url}"/>
            < spring:property name="driverName" value="${driverName}"/>
        </spring:bean>
    < /spring:beans>
    < jdbc-ee:connector name="Database-Connector" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"> 

 < jdbc-ee:query key="InsertQuery" value="INSERT INTO &quot;getData&quot;(ID,NAME,AGE,DESIGNATION)VALUES (#[xpath('//id').text],#[xpath('//name').text],#[xpath('//age').text],#[xpath('//designation').text])"></jdbc-ee:query>  
    < /jdbc-ee:connector>

     <file:connector name="File_Input" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
     <flow name="testxmlFlow1" doc:name="testxmlFlow1"> 
        < file:inbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" moveToPattern="Input.xml" connector-ref="File_Input"></file:inbound-endpoint>  
        < byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte-Array-to-String" >< /byte-array-to-string-transformer >  
        < splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/getData/Data" doc:name="Splitter" >< /splitter >  
        < jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertQuery" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database-Connector" doc:name="Database"></jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint >  
    < /flow >
```

Please help ..... I am getting following exception :-

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1236)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
    at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToDomDocument.transformMessage(XmlToDomDocument.java:63)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

how can I insert the values in which ID and Age are Int ????

Comment: Can you share the complete XML file?

Comment: Hi Victor ... Thank you for your response ... It's now working .... Actually I have to add  
            < file:filename-regex-filter pattern="Input.xml" caseSensitive="false"/ > ... and it's running fine and picking up only "Input.xml " and thus no exception now

Comment: Good to hear it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now working .... Actually I have to add
            `<file:filename-regex-filter pattern="Input.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>` ... and it's running fine and picking up only "Input.xml " and thus no exception now ...  earlier it was picking all the files in the folder and thus that exception raised